# laravel-authentication-acl package not loading css and js (assets)

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-4

> i use laravel framework in my project

i downloaded the package [laravel-authentication-acl](https://github.com/intrip/laravel-authentication-acl)

1-Add to composer.json require field the following lines:

```
 "require": {
    ...
    "jacopo/laravel-authentication-acl": "1.1.*"
  },
```

2- run composer update command. 
 3- opend the file app/config/app.php
    and added to the 'providers' option the following line:

```
 'Jacopo\Authentication\AuthenticationServiceProvider',
```

4-Then run
    this command to publish the configuration files:
     php artisan authentication:prepare

5- run the command:

```
php artisan authentication:install.
```

6- copy

> D:\xamp\htdocs\halls\vendor\jacopo\laravel-authentication-acl\public
>       into D:\xamp\htdocs\halls\public\packages\jacopo

7- run this command
    to publish the configuration files:

```
php artisan authentication:prepare
```

8- run the command:

```
 php artisan authentication:install
```

when i examin the source of the files in browser

> for example
>   http://halls.me/packages/jacopo/laravel-authentication-acl/css/style.css

and click of it it shows Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
that means that the browser not read assets files any help ?

Comment: It appears you did not follow the given installtion instructions: https://github.com/intrip/laravel-authentication-acl/blob/1.1/docs/index.md - What happens if you start fresh and follow the instructions carefully?

Comment: thank you the error was that i'm not publish package  the document not listed this issue and i'm newbie to laravel

Comment: If you start from scratch, and follow the instructions provided by the package, where does it go wrong and what message does it give you? It appears that you must call `authentication:prepare` before `authentication:install`, and you should not need to call `authentication:install` twice as you are doing already. Additionally, copying is not a step you should take as laravel provides packages a way to publish their assets easily (which the `authentication:install` command takes advantage of)

Comment: worked after run this command
php artisan asset:publish vendor/package

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#package-assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you copied:

```
D:\xamp\htdocs\halls\vendor\jacopo\laravel-authentication-acl\public into D:\xamp\htdocs\halls\public\packages\jacopo
```

You should access your files not using:

```
http://halls.me/packages/jacopo/laravel-authentication-acl/css/style.css
```

but

```
http://halls.me/packages/jacopo/css/style.css
```